POWERBI - DAX - RunningTotal
My Azure board is organized in tasks. Each task has a complexity, effort and a ClosedDate. All data are organized in a Table
I need to create a DAX COLUMN with the cumulative sum of Complexity * Effort over ClosedDate and User
Example:



User
PBI Name
Effort
Complexity
Closed Date
CUMULATE




USERA
X1
1
2
2024/07/08
2


USERB
X2
2
3
2024/07/08
6


USERA
X3
1
4
2024/07/09
6


USERB
X4
2
4
2024/07/09
14


USERB
X5
3
1
2024/07/09
17


USERC
X6
1
1
2024/07/09
2




Cumulate = 
VAR user = 'Table'[User]
VAR d = 'Table'[Closed Date]
VAR result = CALCULATE(SUMX('Table', 'Table'[Effort] * 'Table'[Complexity]), 'Table'[User] = user, 'Table'[Closed Date] <= d,  REMOVEFILTERS())

RETURN result


Thanks. What is the need of REMOVEFILTERS?

To escape the evaluation context and see the whole table.

Running total calculations can be made easier using WINDOW function.
Cumulate =
SUMX (
    WINDOW (
        0, ABS, 0, REL,
        SUMMARIZE (
            'Table',
            'Table'[User],
            'Table'[Closed Date],
            'Table'[PBI Name],
            'Table'[Effort],
            'Table'[Complexity]
        ),
        ORDERBY ( 'Table'[Closed Date], ASC, 'Table'[PBI Name], ASC ),
        DEFAULT,
        PARTITIONBY ( 'Table'[User] )
    ),
    'Table'[Effort] * 'Table'[Complexity]
)


It would seem your taskboard would have a 'start date' so you might calculate days as a numeric and apply to your formula.

I don't understand your reply. I need a chart with

X axis (DATE)
Y axis Complexity*Effort
Legend: user


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
